# Can't get my Python program to load when user visits web site

Tags: php, python, web-services

New to Python and the web.  I have a python 2.7 program that uses several html templates and updates info in MYSQL. Moving it to a real web host I have installed Python 2.7 and all the needed modules (like flask) using SSH and can run the command python **init**.py (like I do locally) and it says that it is running on the localhost (on the host server site) so I'm confident the program is executable. I changed permissions using chmod 0755 **init**.py. The site looks for index.php (by default I guess) so I created an index.php with this:

```
<p><?php echo exec('cd ~'); ?></p>
<p><?php echo exec('virtualenv teamingit'); ?></p>
<p><?php echo exec('source teamingit/bin/activate'); ?></p>
<p><?php echo exec('cd public_html'); ?></p>
<p><?php echo exec('python __init__.py'); ?></p>
```

When you go to the site it shows the message for the virtualenv (i.e. Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.) so at least part of the PHP code is executing  but then it just leaves only that message on the screen rather than rendering the first template.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious to python/web veterans but I'm stuck, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Why run this with php? You may want to consider WSGI.

Comment: I appreciate the comment - I am investigating WSGI - any gems of knowledge you can offer is appreciated - I'm checking to make sure my host provider supports mod_WSGI - I think then I need to work on some configuration file for the server to use - does that sound like the right direction?  Again any other guidance is appreciated as this part is really new to me.

Comment: My host provider just replied "our managed products support Passenger_WSGI. Python on our platform is geared more towards the use with PHP. " so I guess I need to get the index.php to call the python program - again any help is appreciated.

Comment: Update - I created a vi passenger_wsgi.py with the following:

    import sys, os
    virt_binary = "/home/%USER%/pyenv/bin/python"
    if sys.executable != virt_binary: os.execl(virt_binary, virt_binary, *sys.argv)
    sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
    from app.helloworld import app as application

created a helloworld.py and created a .htaccess with the following: PassengerEnabled on
PassengerAppRoot /home/%USER%/helloworld
PassengerPython /home/%USER%/pyenv/bin/python (replaced the correct user) and get this error: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.php5,.....